# ReviewBoard: How to filter out reviews marked as Ship It?

Tags: review-board

In ReviewBoard, I have 4765 Incoming Reviews. I would like to know which ones of those reviews I have not clicked Ship It on - i.e., the reviews that I haven't looked at yet.

I thought that if I click Ship It, the review would disappear from my Incoming Reviews list. But that is not the case - my Incoming Reviews contain reviews that I have clicked Ship It on.

How do I filter out the ones that I have clicked Ship It on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not very straightforward, but a combination of following two should be useful.

1. Enable the 'My Comments' columns in the dashboard. [Check how to customize columns.](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/users/dashboard/#customizable-columns)

   From the manual: 'My Comments' Shows a green comment flag if you have any unpublished comments on the review request, or a blue comment flag if you have published comments. This allows you to quickly see which review request you’ve addressed.
2. [Sort](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/users/dashboard/#sorting) this column and the pending review requests should appear on top of the table.

Comment: That's a great tip. Unfortunately I can't sort by My Comments (at least not in ReviewBoard 1.7.22), but at least I can scan the list to see which reviews I have not commented on yet. Thanks!